# Can a single JVM gateway process control multiple py4j processes/instances?

Tags: java, py4j

Python has its *GIL* and is ever and anon single-threaded.  On the other hand there is no clear reason why a single *JVM* instance could not hand off the *Gateway* responsibilities to each of N threads - each one handling a separate the socket communication with a separate *python* process . Is this actually possible with *py4j* ?

Answer (score 1):

A single GatewayServer instance on the Java side can handle N python processes.

The server thread accepts connections on a thread and then spawn a new thread for each new connection/python process.

You can read more about the [threading model used in Py4J here](https://www.py4j.org/advanced_topics.html#using-single-threading-model-pinned-thread).

Comment: Thanks for those docs.  It is not clear to me yet how to get the multiple _py4j_ processes.  Note that section  3.4.  _Using Single Threading Model (pinned thread)_   is for _python_ initiated processes (the opposite of what I want).   Section 3.5 _Initiating the communication from the Java side_  is what I need but does not clearly state how to do the multiple processes.  Do you see how to apply _3.5_ to get the multiple py4j processes?